# Pointer dimensions when copying an address of multidimensional arra to a pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

When we have a multidimensional array, and we hope to use a pointer to point to its address. In a book, it says we will do as following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a[3][4][5];
    int *p[5];
    p = a;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I am quiet confused about the following points:

1. When I typed the code into CLion, it gives a warning:`Incompatible pointer types 'int[5] *' and 'int[3][4][5]'`, and why is that?
2. Why does the pointer array `*p` contains 5 variables instead of 3 variables?
3. How to use this pointer `*p`?

Thanks.

Comment: `p = a;` is illegal code. Your compiler tells you this. The output of any executable that your compiler generates anyway is undefined.

Comment: `p` is an array and it is not possible to assign to an array. You can only assign to the individual members of an array (when those are not arrays themself)

Answer (score 1):

1) Because... they are different pointer types! ;) Specifically, `a` is a three dimensional array of integers, while `p` is a one dimensional array of pointers to ints. Got that? `a` contains ints, `p` contains pointers to ints.

2) Because  line `int *p[5];` declares it to be 5 long. In C you define how big an array is by the number in the `[]`.

3) Well, if you want p to point to a you would need to make some part of it point to a, as an example `p[0] = a;`